# Is there any way to specify delete permissions in svn?

Tags: svn, permissions, authorization

Some users are committing svn deletes by mistake, and I would like to restrict these accidental deletes, while retaining read/write permissions. Of course, they could overwrite files with zeros, but that doesn't accidentally.
I did some googling and found there was a python file that claimed to do this, but as svn has changed sites, the file is lost. Is there anyone who has that file, or have any other way to add a delete permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing's first: do you understand that nothing is actually deleted from the repository? You can always restore any version of a file, let alone restore "deleted" ones.

You can try implementing this with a pre-commit hook. See [this](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook).

Answer (score 2):

Please don’t do this.

Even if you manage to create a hook that will prevent deletions, what if they have a legitimate reason for `svn delete`ing?  Then they will be coming to you and complaining.  Is the hook going to be effectively a pop-up that says “are you sure you want to delete”?  If so it will quickly be ignored, and it isn’t that useful anyway since any SVN action can be undone.

Educate your users on how to recover accidentally deleted files — don’t try to code around them.  That doesn’t solve the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid not. SVN will only grant read/write permission, where writing subsumes deleting.